# Webpack lazy loading Leaflet-Geoman

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I am trying to lazy load js drawing library [Leaflet-Geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)

I am using webpack and the following code to load

```
  private async loadGeoman () {
    await import(/* webpackChunkName: "leaflet-geoman" */ '@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free')
  }
```

And then using it in the following function

```
  public async enableDrawing (type: TaggedType, item: any) {
    await this.loadGeoman()

    this._map.pm.enableDraw(type, {
       ...
    })
    ....
```

I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enableDraw')
    at DrawingService.enableDrawing (drawing.service.ts?af11:192)
    at eval (drawing.service.ts?af11:75)
```

It seems like the library isn't hooking up on leaflet map. Leaflet map is created before the library is loaded and i am assuming that's the problem, but i don't know how to go around it

Comment: Where are you assigned `this._map`?

Comment: map is initialized in a seperate service after the DOM has loaded, and then passed to the drawing service throu a "set" method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geoman is adding it self to the map while initializing the map. This means if `L.Map` is called before Geoman-Script is added to your site, Geoman will not be added to the map.
Then you need to call `L.PM.reInitLayer(map)`.

```
public async enableDrawing (type: TaggedType, item: any) {
    await this.loadGeoman();

    L.PM.reInitLayer(this._map);

    this._map.pm.enableDraw(type, {
       ...
    })
```